# JS. Unable to output float with alert()

Tags: javascript, html

(repost because my former post was unable to get bumped up for some reason)
I currently have a script that takes numbers from a text area and does all sorts of calculations with them. I am having trouble with my standard deviation function because it will not output the value even though it's type is number, and it is positive (.56).

When I run this code

```
var variance = findVariance(array);
    variance = parseFloat(variance);
    alert(typeof variance);
```

the result is

> number

And the value is .56 (which I know because when I don't use parseFloat it returns .56 as a string). So I am baffled when I run this code

```
alert("variance " + variance);
alert("sd" + Math.sqrt(variance));
```

and both alerts return

```
NaN
```

This is the code that creates the textarea, calls the function processData( which gathers the input from myTextArea into an array and then calls the function findStandardDeviation) I can post the variance function as well if you'd like.

```
<textarea id="myTextArea" rows = "7" cols = "50"></textarea><br>

<button onclick="processData()">Done</button>

<p id = "sd"></p>

<script type = "text/javascript">

    var standard_deviation = 0;

    var sdOutput = document.getElementById('sd'); 

function processData()
{
    var arrayOfLines = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value.split('\n');


    findStandardDeviation(arrayOfLines);
}
```

And here is the my reduced script:

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
  
  var mean = 0;
  var median = 0;
  var count = length;
  var mode = 0;
 
  var standard_deviation = 0;

  var meanOutput = document.getElementById('mean'); 
  var countOutput = document.getElementById('count'); 
  var sumOutput = document.getElementById('sum'); 
  var varianceOutput = document.getElementById('variance'); 
  var sdOutput = document.getElementById('sd'); 

 function processData()
 {
  var arrayOfLines = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value.split('\n');

  var sum = findSum(arrayOfLines);
  findMeanOutput(arrayOfLines, sum);
  findVariance(arrayOfLines);
  findStandardDeviation(arrayOfLines);
 }

 function findSum (array)
 {
  var count = array.length;
  var sum = 0;

  for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a++)
  {
   sum += parseInt(array[a]);
  }
  
  countOutput.innerHTML = "Count: " + array.length; 
  sumOutput.innerHTML = "Sum: " + JSON.stringify(sum); 
  sum = parseInt(sum);
  return sum;
 }

 function findMean (array) //Used for finding mean and then returning it
 {
  var sum = 0;

  for(var a = 0; a < array.length; a++)
  {
   sum += parseFloat(array[a]);
  }

  mean = sum/array.length;
  return mean; 
 }

 function findMeanOutput (array, sum) //finds mean and then establishes it as the mean for users input
 {
  mean = sum/array.length;
  meanOutput.innerHTML = "Mean: " +  mean; 
 }

 

 function findVariance (array) 
 {
  var mean = findMean(array);

  var variance = "Variance: " + findMean(array.map(function(num) 
  {
   return Math.pow(num - mean, 2);
  })).toFixed(2);

  varianceOutput.innerHTML = "Variance: " + variance;
  return variance;
 }

 function findStandardDeviation (array) 
 {
  var variance = findVariance(array);
  variance = parseFloat(variance);
  alert(typeof variance);
  alert("variance " + variance);
  alert("sd" + Math.sqrt(variance));
  sdOutput.innerHTML = "Standard Deviation: " + Math.sqrt(variance).toFixed(2); 
 }

</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p> Please enter a series of numbers, each separated by a new line.<br><p>

<textarea id="myTextArea" rows = "7" cols = "50"></textarea><br>

<button onclick="processData()">Done</button>

<p id = "mean"></p>
<p id = "count"></p>
<p id = "sum"></p>
<p id = "variance"></p>
<p id = "sd"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`variance` variable returned from `findVariance()` call includes the string `"Variance: "`. You can use `.match()` with `RegExp` `/[\d.]+/` to match digits or digits followed by `"."` followed by  digit within string and `+` operator to convert string to number

```js
var mean = 0;
var median = 0;
var count = length;
var mode = 0;

var standard_deviation = 0;

var meanOutput = document.getElementById('mean');
var countOutput = document.getElementById('count');
var sumOutput = document.getElementById('sum');
var varianceOutput = document.getElementById('variance');
var sdOutput = document.getElementById('sd');

function processData() {
  var arrayOfLines = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value.split('\n');

  var sum = findSum(arrayOfLines);
  findMeanOutput(arrayOfLines, sum);
  findVariance(arrayOfLines);
  findStandardDeviation(arrayOfLines);
}

function findSum(array) {
  var count = array.length;
  var sum = 0;

  for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
    sum += parseInt(array[a]);
  }

  countOutput.innerHTML = "Count: " + array.length;
  sumOutput.innerHTML = "Sum: " + JSON.stringify(sum);
  sum = parseInt(sum);
  return sum;
}

function findMean(array) //Used for finding mean and then returning it
{
  var sum = 0;

  for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
    sum += parseFloat(array[a]);
  }

  mean = sum / array.length;
  return mean;
}

function findMeanOutput(array, sum) //finds mean and then establishes it as the mean for users input
{
  mean = sum / array.length;
  meanOutput.innerHTML = "Mean: " + mean;
}



function findVariance(array) {
  var mean = findMean(array);

  var variance = "Variance: " + findMean(array.map(function(num) {
    return Math.pow(num - mean, 2);
  })).toFixed(2);
  varianceOutput.innerHTML = "Variance: " + variance;
  return variance;
}

function findStandardDeviation(array) {
  var variance = findVariance(array);
  variance = parseFloat(+variance.match(/[\d.]+/)[0]);
  console.log(variance);
  alert(typeof variance);
  alert(`variance ${variance}`);
  alert(`sd ${Math.sqrt(variance)}`);
  sdOutput.innerHTML = "Standard Deviation: " + Math.sqrt(variance).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <p> Please enter a series of numbers, each separated by a new line.<br>
    <p>

      <textarea id="myTextArea" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea><br>

      <button onclick="processData()">Done</button>

      <p id="mean"></p>
      <p id="count"></p>
      <p id="sum"></p>
      <p id="variance"></p>
      <p id="sd"></p>



</body>

</html>
```